# Log results in Jupyter notebook and shell at the same time

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter-lab

I have place a code snnipet at `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup` that redirects the output of a print statement that is executed on the Jupyter notebook to the cell, which is basically the following.

```
sys.stdout = open(1,'w')
```

The problem with this is that the the result of the print within the Jupyter notebook is never shown again, it is only redirected to the [shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/td3RY.png) and it is not shown in the [notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07eJa.png).

How I could send the result to the shell but also keep the result shown in the Jupyter notebook?

Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it. Here is the solution.

```
import sys
import logging

class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self, filename = 1):
        self.terminal = sys.stdout
        self.log = open(filename, "a")
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.terminal, attr)
    def write(self, message):
        self.log.write(message)
        
    def flush(self):
        self.log.flush()
```

By placing this file on the startup folder, it will log prints to the shell and also to the notebook.